# Connect to external MySQL server on Android

Tags: android, mysql, jtds, android-sql

I've followed this tutorial: http://www.parallelcodes.com/connect-android-to-ms-sql-database-2/

So Im using jtds-1.2.7.jar on Android Studio in trying to connect my app to an external MySQL server, 000webhost to be specific.

I keep getting this error:

E/SQL Exception: I/O Error: Unknown packet type 0x46

Here's the code:

```
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.util.Log;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;

public class SQLConnection {

String ip = "sql12.000webhost.com:3306";
String classs = "net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver";
String db = "db_name";
String un = "username";
String password = "password";

public Connection CONN() {
    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
            .permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
    Connection conn = null;
    String ConnURL = null;
    try {
        Class.forName(classs);
        ConnURL = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://" + ip + ";"
                + "databaseName=" + db + ";user=" + un + ";password="
                + password + ";";

        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(ConnURL);
    } catch (SQLException se) {
        Log.e("SQL Exception", se.getMessage());
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        Log.e("Class Not Found", e.getMessage());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Exception", e.getMessage());
    }
    return conn;
}

}
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Thank you very much!

Cheers!

Comment: Umm, I AM trying to connect to a MySQL server as you can see

Comment: Then you have to use the mysql-connector not jtds